# Volume of a solid enclosed by the hyperboloid and cone

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

> Compute the volume of the solid inside the cone $2(x^2+y^2)=z^2$ and hyperboloid $x^2+y^2=z^2-a^2.$
>
> Source Demidovich, task 2024

**My attempt:**

Because of the symmetry with respect to the $xy$ plane, we can compute the volume above the plane and multiply it by $2$.

Intersection of the cone and hyperboloid : $$\begin{cases}x^2+y^2=\frac{z^2}2\\x^2+y^2=z^2-a^2\end{cases}\implies x^2+y^2=\frac{z^2}2=a^2$$ is the circle of the radius $a$. I used the cylindrical coordinates $$\begin{aligned}x=r\cos\varphi\\y=r\sin\varphi\\z=z, r\in[0,a]\\\varphi\in[0,2\pi]\\z\in\left(\sqrt 2r,\sqrt{r^2+a^2}\right)\end{aligned}$$
so the Jacobian equals $r$ and volume is $\begin{aligned}2\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^a\int_{\sqrt 2r}^{\sqrt{r^2+a^2}}r\mathrm dz\mathrm dr\mathrm d\varphi&=4\pi\int_0^a\left(\sqrt{r^2+a^2}-\sqrt 2r\right)\mathrm dr\\&=4\pi\int_0^a\left(r\sqrt{r^2+a^2}-\sqrt 2r^2\right)\mathrm dr\\&=4\pi\left(\frac{(r^2+a^2)^{3/2}}3-\sqrt 2\frac{r^3}3\right)\Big|_0^a\\&=4\pi\left(\frac{2\sqrt 2 a^3}3-\sqrt 2\frac{a^3}3\right)\\&=\frac43a^3\pi,\end{aligned}$ but the solution is $\frac43a^3\pi(\sqrt 2-1),$ and I can't find my mistake. Can anybody see it?

Comment: There is just a minor error near the end: it should be
$$4\pi\left(\frac{(r^2+a^2)^{3/2}}3-\sqrt 2\frac{r^3}3\right)\Big|_0^a=
4\pi\left(\frac{2\sqrt{2}a^3}3-\color{blue}{\frac{a^3}3}-\sqrt 2\frac{a^3}3\right)=\frac43a^3\pi(\sqrt 2-1).$$

Comment: @RobertZ, thank you!